# Compilation error with Rust: "cannot find -lgcc_eh" on Windows

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Issues with Rust compiling. While trying to compile Hello World example via VS Code there a problem was found: "note: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

I reinstalled all files. But that was not helpful

Comment: Try using the x86_64-windows-msvc target